# How to launch a Firefox OS app on startup

Tags: mozilla, firefox-os

Is there some way to launch a Firefox OS app on startup?  I originally thought it could be dictated in the app manifest but as far as I know, no such property exists.

Does some event fire when Firefox OS boots up?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible yet. Though you might want to file it on Bugzilla as a feature: (http://bugzilla.mozilla.org)